# Blender Lighting / Light HDR - symmetrize / symmetry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting, hdri

there is any way to symmetrize the lights that are cast to object from HDR maps?

I need to bake combined textures with symmetrize lights for mobile game.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn these off, so your textures won't be affected at all from your lighting/surrounding objects/reflections etc and will be affected by the lighting of the game engine instead when you use them:

[image]

If you still want it to be lighting affected, then that depends on your lighting setup/HDRI.

Comment: The problem is i need to bake those lights

Answer (score 0):

Use this node set-up,  [image]

Basically the gradient node is used to create the half of a sphere, we will use it to hide the "left side" of the HDRI and replace it by the same picture mirrored thanks to a negative scale[image]

Comment: Mirroring of hdri works but lighting on object are not simmetrized. :<